# Can differential equations have orders of derivatives that are dependent on the independent variable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

I was wondering if you can construct and/or solve a differential equation of the following form,
$$\frac{d^{(f(x))}y}{dx^{(f(x))}}=g(x)$$
where $y$ is dependent only on $x$ and $f(x)$ is a function whose range consists of integers only, say $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor $.

A buddy of mine was wondering something similar by considering a DE like
$$\frac{d^{(\lfloor x\rfloor\pmod2+1)}y}{dx^{(\lfloor x\rfloor\pmod2+1)}}=x$$
so that the order of the derivative would alternate between $1$ and $2$, and it struck me as an interesting question. I don't know/understand as much DE theory as I'd like to, so I would like to know if this sort of situation is at all possible, and if so, what might a physical interpretation be?

My first instinct is that it's not possible, but supposing it were, I expect some piecewise definitions would be involved.

Comment: In that equation, the order is constant in intervals, so you can handle each interval separately and pretty much do anything you might want.

Comment: Of course the situationis possible:you yourself wrote an equation of that sort! As for the physical interpretation... why would one expect any random equationto have one?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks, I wasn't sure if I was "allowed" to approach the equation in a piecemeal fashion. As for whether there might be a physical interpretation... I suppose I don't expect it to, but I'm curious to see if there is any kind of situation that would warrant a model like the DE that alternates between orders 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

See book "The Fractional Calculus.  Theory and Applications of Differentiation and Integration to Arbitrary Order"  by Oldham and Spanier 2002.  Good luck!